# Limited access gets added automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online

i have been sharing folders to external clients. Each time when i add a user to a folder (edit\Read permission) a limited access permission gets added automatically. and has been creating problems so i removed the style readers group. But the problem is now no one can access the site as used to how do i get back or restore the access to the previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Limited Access` is a special system permission added by SharePoint automatically.

There are many parts in SharePoint which are security trimmed. Now imagine a situation, when you want to share some folder with special group, but this group doesn't have any permissions on the site yet. So you are adding permissions directly to the folder. In that case your group still doesn't have a permission to parent security object, web. If a user from this group tries to open this shared folder, he will get access denied, which is not correct, since you want him to see this folder.

To avoid such a strange situation, SharePoint also added `Limited Access` permission to this group (only in case if the group doesn't have permission on a root web for example). By deleting `Style Resource Readers` group you effectively removed permissions from the web and now have situation described above, when your users are getting access denied.

You can either explicitly give Read permissions to your users on a web, or you can "Restore" `Style Resource Readers` group. For restore, you need to create this group first (**don't give any permissions when creating**, this is important). Then create some temporary list, break permissions inheritance for this list, under permissions for the list add `Style Resource Readers` group. Now go to Site Settings -> Permissions -> Check permissions, enter `Style Resource Readers` and make sure that now `Style Resource Readers` has Limited Access given directly. Add required users to `Style Resource Readers` (`NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users` or `Everyone` or any others depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

If you modified the permissions in a subsite, you can always choose to inherit permissions again from the parent.

If you're working on the root web inside your site collection, then you won't be able to get back the modified permissions. You can however give all users read only permission to the site by adding them to the visitors group, then start applying extra permissions anywhere else.

Comment: this is a document library i have given permission on folders. this site has unique permission and external users have access to the folders.

Comment: You can inherit the permissions again from the site where the document library exists, and the permissions will be the same as they were before

Comment: It gives me warning "Hold on: This site include things that have been shared to specific people.Those people will lose access". I am using sharepoint online platforms there are users who only have access to specific folders.

Comment: @Rinu If your list has its permission inheritance broken from the site, and the folders inside did the same thing with their permission inheritance broken from the list, you can revert the list back to its original permissions by clicking "delete unique permissions" from the ribbon in the list permissions page. This won't delete the unique permissions on the folders